# Change language in WordPress using custom Code

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I have site in WP that have multiple languages like `(English,German and French)`.there url look like this `:http://example.com(english). http://example.com/?lang=fr(french) and http://example.com/?lang=de(german)`
I am trying to change language before page loads.so i try some code on `index.php` but it creates issue.
My code is :

```
$currentUrl = 'this is current page url';
 $store_code = "french";
switch ($store_code) { 
    case 'french':
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=fr"; 

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break;
case 'german':
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=de"; 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break; 
case 'mandarin':
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=zh"; 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break;   
    default:
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl; 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break;
}
Output.
```

It generate url like this with empty page.

```
http://example.com/?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr?lang=fr
```

Comment: `but it creates issue` What issue is it creating ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner i have add the error in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using condition before the switch statment.It works

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
 $store_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->getData("foo") !='bar')
{

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData("foo","bar");
switch ($store_code) { 
    case 'french':
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=fr"; 
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break;
case 'german':
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=de"; 
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break; 
case 'mandarin':
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=zh"; 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break;   
    default:
       $_baseurl = $currentUrl; 
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
        break;
}
}
```

While on Magento side i set the session before the layout load event like this.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData("foo","magento");
```

Comment: This solution is not desirable, it will result in invalid URLs when $currentUrl already contains a `?` .You better use `http_build_query` to keep possible  other GET-params intact and create a valid URL

Comment: @Dr.Molle check now.I think its now perfect for language switcher on session base.I am using Magento with WP.

Answer (score -1):

It is generating `output` like this because you have taken only **french** in switch.So every time it is getting that `case` only. What you can do is **make an array** of that language and after that use it in `switch` like this:

```
    $currentUrl = 'this is current page url';
    $store_code = array('french', 'german', 'mandarin');
    foreach($store_code as $mylang){
        switch ($mylang) { 
            case 'french':
               $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=fr"; 

                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
                break;
        case 'german':
               $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=de"; 
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
                break; 
        case 'mandarin':
               $_baseurl = $currentUrl."?lang=zh"; 
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
                break;   
            default:
               $_baseurl = $currentUrl; 
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='{$_baseurl}'</script>";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Please let me know the output here.

Comment: Thanks but french is just a example.Like when page loads i have one  code ,Now i have to set condition on that code basis.Hope you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: the problem is it is calling french agian and agian.while i think after first attempt is shouldn't do this.

Comment: Sorry but still I didn't get you .. which code are you talking about ? And have you try above code ? What is it giving ?

Comment: I am coming to this page from another page where i set the code.this code may be french or german.So i use switch statement to check and load that language accordingly.

Comment: Ok .. So from which page you are coming, have you passed any parameters ? And if you don't mind can I have a look of that page also ?

Comment: I am coming from magento Site.Issue is in this code i put in question.Yes i have code parameter in session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67296/discussion-between-rohil-phpbeginner-and-mahmood-rehman).